# Phe- prefix - etymology

Tags: meaning, prefixes

What is the meaning, origin and usage of the "***phe-***" prefix?

According to one source, it means "to speak".

Comment: Any dictionary should have the etymology you need.

Comment: The root morpheme of *phenomenon* is *pheno-*. [Wiktionary's etymology](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phenomenon) shows, From Late Latin *phaenomenon* (“appearance”), from Ancient Greek φαινόμενον (*phainomenon*, “thing appearing to view”), neuter present passive participle of φαίνω (*phainō*, “I show”).

Comment: [Phenomenon](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=phenomenon&searchmode=term)

Comment: It's just a coincidence that the _-no_ ending of one root got stuck next to the _men-_ beginning of the next one. In other words, _-nomen-_ is not a Constituent of _phenomenon_.

Comment: OP here, thanks for answering guys.  I wasn't sure if this was a real prefix, but I did notice the pattern that appeared to have a meaning deeper than just the sound it makes.  You guys are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etymonline.com's entry for *[phenomenon](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=phenomenon)* (shown below) makes it clear that rather than *phe* + *nomen*, the word's origin is from  *phainein*, which  etymonline's *[phantasm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phantasm&allowed_in_frame=0)* entry glosses as  “to bring to light, make appear; come to light, be seen, appear; explain, expound, inform against; appear to be so”.

> 1570s, “fact, occurrence,” from Late Latin *phænomenon*, from Greek *phainomenon* “that which appears or is seen,” noun use of neuter present participle of *phainesthai* “to appear,” passive of *phainein* (see *[phantasm](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phantasm&allowed_in_frame=0)*).

Note that *phe* itself is not a recognized prefix.  However, if you search for *[phe](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=phe&searchmode=none)* in etymonline, the site will display several pages of words containing the text-string *phe*.  One finds various origins of words beginning with *phe*:  for *[pheasant](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pheasant&allowed_in_frame=0)*,  “Phasis, river flowing into the Black Sea”; for *[phenol](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phenol&allowed_in_frame=0)* etc., prefix *[pheno-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pheno-&allowed_in_frame=0)* is a “word-forming element in science meaning "pertaining to or derived from benzene," from *[phene](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=phene&allowed_in_frame=0)*”; for *[pheromone](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pheromone&allowed_in_frame=0)*,  from Greek *pherein*, “to carry”.

Comment: The only slight inaccuracy in that is that _φαίνεσθαι_ is not the passive of _φαίνω_, but rather the middle. _Φαίνω_ in turn is a yod-present formed on the basis of the Proto-Indo-European root _*bʰeh₂_ ‘shine’, enlarged by a nasal suffix.  

Apart from being related to ‘phantom’ and ‘phantasm’ (and ‘fantasy’, for that matter), it is also the same root that gives ‘phase’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I'm willing to suppose you are correct, although except for using Latin rather than Greek letters the etymonline entry seems similar to the OED1 entry that refers to "absol. use of pr. pple. passive of φαίνειν"

Comment: the form is both middle and passive in form, but it can be seen from other parts of the paradigm (where there are separate passive forms) that _φαίνεσθαι_ in this sense is a middle verb, not a passive verb.

Comment: Hrm, that got botched up a bit. Was supposed to say, “_φαινομένον_ is both middle and passive in form”, of course.